# Может ли strcmp ввести себя некорректно?

Tags: c

```
token = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &savedptr);
char* ptr;
while (token)
{
    nom_serveur = strtok_r(token, ":", &ptr);
    for (int i = 0; i < serveur_connected -> taille; i++)
    {
        if (memcmp(nom_serveur, serveur_connected -> table[i].nom, strlen(serveur_connected -> table[i].nom)) == 0)
        {
            index_serveur = recherche_port_serveur(serveur_connected, nom_serveur);

            if (index_serveur != -1)
            {
                serveur_donnee.sin_port = serveur_connected -> table[index_serveur].port;
                serveur_donnee.sin_addr.s_addr = serveur_connected -> table[index_serveur].address;
                serveur_donnee.sin_family = AF_INET;
                len = sizeof(serveur_donnee);
                char requete_serveur[BUFLEN];
                int user = recherche_login(users_connected, client.sin_port, client.sin_addr.s_addr);
                if (user != -1)
                {                                                
                    send_packet.type = ACK;
                    send_packet.ack = ++users_connected -> table[user].ack;
                    strcpy(send_packet.packet.data,"");
                    from_struct_to_buff(send_packet, requete);

                    if ((sendto(fd, requete, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client, lenclient) == -1))
                        raler(1, "Erreur send");
                    snprintf(requete_serveur, MAX_BUFLEN, "ecrire %s %s", users_connected -> table[user].login, ptr);
                    send_packet.type = SEQ;
                    send_packet.num_seq = serveur_connected -> table[index_serveur].num_seq;                                            
                    memset(send_packet.packet.data, 0, 1024);
                    printf("nom recherché: %s avant memcpy\n", nom_serveur);
                    memcpy(send_packet.packet.data, requete_serveur, strlen(requete_serveur) + 1);
                    printf("nom recherché: %s après memcpy\n", nom_serveur);

                    from_struct_to_buff(send_packet, requete);

                    if ((sendto(fd, requete, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serveur_donnee, len) == -1))
                        raler(1, "Erreur send putain la");

                    if ((recvfrom(fd, requete, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serveur_donnee, &len) == -1))
                        raler(1, "Pb de recvfrom"); 

                    recv_packet = from_char_to_struct(requete);
                    printf("nom recherché: %s après from_char_to_struct\n", nom_serveur);

                    if(recv_packet.type == ACK && recv_packet.ack == send_packet.num_seq + 1)
                        serveur_connected -> table[index_serveur].num_seq++;
                }
                else
                    printf("GEREEEEER");
            }
            else
                printf("GEREEEEER");
        }
    }
    token = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &savedptr);
}
```

При i=1, переменная `nom_serveur` больше не содержит данных. Пробовала тоже самое с `memcmp`, не помогло

UPD: проблема вызвана функцией `from_char_to_struct`
:

```
Frame from_char_to_struct(char requete[BUFLEN])
{
    Frame f;
    char* req = requete;
    char* saveptr;
    char* type = strtok_r(req, " ", &saveptr);
    char* num = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &saveptr);

    if (strcmp(type, "ACK") == 0)
    {
        f.type = ACK;
        f.ack = atoi(num);
    }

    if (strcmp(type, "SEQ") == 0)
    {
        f.type = SEQ;
        f.num_seq = atoi(num);
    }

    if (strcmp(type, "FIN") == 0)
    {
        f.type = FIN;
        f.num_seq = atoi(num);
    }

    memset(f.packet.data, 0, 1024);
    memcpy(f.packet.data, saveptr, strlen(saveptr) + 1);

    return f;
}
```

Comment: Ну так... ищите, куда делись данные. `strcmp` тут ни при чем. А кто виноват - из вашего огрызка кода не видно. Может это `recherche_port_serveur` вам все испортил.

Comment: Отдельно стоит заметить, что один раз вызвать `strtok_r(token, ":", &token)` еще можно, но делать это в цикле - грубое нарушение внешней спецификации `strtok_r`. Из вашего кода не ясно, делается ли это в цикле.

Comment: `nom_serveur` может менять 1)recherche_port_serveur (если в втором параметре отсутствует const 2) то что в "...".

Comment: Такие проблемы решаются дебаггером.

Comment: @nick_n_a я исправила код. Проблема вызвана функцией `from_char_to_struct`, но я совсем не вижу связи.Могли бы вы посмотреть?

Comment: @AnT исправила вопрос. Могли бы вы взглянуть?

Comment: Вы в своем коде постоянно используете этот `saveptr`, который вы передавали последним параметром в `strtok_r`. Вы, я вижу, ожидаете, что там будет храниться указатель на остаток строки. Может это и так, но ничего подобного `strtok_r` не гарантирует. Содержимое  `saveptr` является неопределенным и вас не касается. Вам не разрешается делать никаких предположений об этом содержимом или использовать его в своих целях. Проблема, скорее всего, не в этом, но тем не менее.

Comment: `snprintf(requete_serveur, MAX_BUFLEN, ...` - почему вдруг `MAX_BUFLEN`? Что такое `MAX_BUFLEN` и чем оно отличается от `BUFLEN`?

Comment: @AnT для `strtok_r` чтобы получить остаток строки, будет ли хорошо работать способ `char* rest = strtok_r(NULL, "", &ptr);`? Безопасно ли?